# How to improve a script for checking that files from one driver are present in another drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I'm trying to check if some files in drive A are present or missing in another drive B, so I did this little script:

```
import os
import subprocess

# drive A
SOURCE_PATH = '/media/username/8e223d5b-2755-4e9f-a2f6-fac5e762e836/username'
# drive B
DESTINY_PATH = '/home/username/'
SUCCESS_CODE = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    source_file = ''
    destiny_file = ''
    for source_actualdir, source_subdir, source_dirFiles in os.walk(SOURCE_PATH):
        for source_filename in source_dirFiles:
            for destiny_actualdir, destiny_subdir, destiny_dirFiles in os.walk(DESTINY_PATH):
                for destiny_filename in destiny_dirFiles:
                    source_file = os.path.join(source_actualdir, source_filename)
                    destiny_file = os.path.join(destiny_actualdir, destiny_filename)
                    response = subprocess.run(['diff',  '-s', f'{source_file}', f'{destiny_file}'], capture_output=True)
                    if response.returncode == SUCCESS_CODE:
                        print(f'Coincidencia {source_file} == {destiny_file}')
                        break
            print(f'File {source_file} is missing in {DESTINY_PATH}')
```

but I find it too slow when running it (I have to check 242603 files for a total of 145GBs) and I'd like to speed it up but I don't know how.

What can I use for such a task?

Comment: What you're doing is for every file in the source, search every file in the dest, and then diff them. What might be quicker is building a `set` of all files in both directories, and then checking overlap.

Comment: Tangentially, the code you put inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` should be absolutely trivial. The condition is only useful when you `import` this code; if all the useful functionality is excluded when you `import`, you will never want to do that anyway. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/874188

Comment: A common approach is to obtain checksums for all the files; the ones which exist in both sets are duplicates. Depending on your desired precision, MD5 might be good enough, but it is more prone to collisions  than SHA1 or SHA256.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, say drive A contains foo, bar, bat, and drive B contains fizz, buzz, bat, then you're doing these checks:

```
foo, fizz
foo, buzz
foo, bat
bat, fizz
bar, buzz,
bar, bat
bat, fizz
bat, buzz
bat, bat => success
```

So the number of things you have to check is `len(A) * len(B)`.

Whereas, say you had

```
A = {"foo", "bar", "bat"}
B = {"fizz", "buzz", "bat"}
```

You could loop through A and check if it's in B. Then you're only looping through one thing - you should do the smaller of these if there's a significant difference.

Then you've got the problem of how to check if the files are the same. I would use [MurmurHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash). There are [Python bindings here](https://pypi.org/project/mmh3/).

So instead of diffing everything, when you loop through you calculate the hash, and store it against the path (in a dict). Then you check the overlap again, but this time, for any matches you know that the content is the same, and what the paths are.

Something like:

```
import mmh3

def get_path_map(file_paths): 
    d = {}
    for path in file_paths:
        with open(path) as f:
            hs = mmh3.hash(f.read())
        d[hs] = path
    return d

sources = get_path_map(...)  # you can do this bit
dests = get_path_map(...)

for hs, path in sources.items():
    if hs in dests:
        print(f"Match found: '{path}' is the same as '{dests[hs]}'")
```